# Hibernate JPA Native Query ResultSet

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I need to get a resultset via executing a native query in Hibernate. Though I am using EntityManager, the query and resultSet may not be entities.

A need to get ResultSet that is of List. Since the select output may vary (read dynamic) i cannot use  SqlResultSetMapping.

When i tried the below code i got a result. Since what i am requesting is a single valued result. (Hibernate JPA)

```
Query query = manager.createNativeQuery("select name from fresher_test where id=1");
List<Object> amount = query.getResultList();

if(amount == null)
 {
    System.out.println("Hey its a null");
    return;
 }
 for(Object e : arr)
 {
   System.out.println(e.toString());
 }
```

The output was : Alice

When I tried to get more than one select out from the same code with Query as **select name,designation from fresher_test where id=1**

The output was : [Ljava.lang.Object;@8b1a4f

An object. How do I get the fields from this object?. I tried to typecast object e (List l = (List) e;) to a List but i throws java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List.

This there a way that I could get the values in a List or Array ??

Note : I cannot use a result class/entity since the results could be dynamic.

Comment: List<Object[]> amount =  null;
   amount= query.getResultList();
   for(Object[] e : amount)
   {
    System.out.println(e[0] +""+ e[1]);
   }

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When fetching multiple columns, the result is a `List<Object[]>`. Each `Object[]` contains one column of the row. So in your case, each `Object[]` would contain 2 elements, the first one being the name, and the second one being the designation.

Note that `getResultList()` will never return null. You shouldn't check that.

Answer (score 2):

JPA 2.0, if you want your result in a custom bean:

make a bean with specific constructor

```
package my.package;
public class MyBean{
...
    public MyBean(Long id, String desc, Long id2)
```

then in your entity o mapping, make your named query like this

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myNamedQuery", 
    query = "select new my.package.MyBean(e.idSomething, e.description, e.secondId) 
             from DBEntity e")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following

```
NativeQueryImpl nativeQuery = (NativeQueryImpl) query; 

nativeQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE); 
    List<Map<String,Object>> result = nativeQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy, you saved my day. This solution is working as Wonder.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem and here how to resolve it :

```
List<User> records = entityManager.createNamedQuery("latestStatusByUser").getResultList();
List<User> userRecords = new ArrayList<User>();
Iterator it = records.iterator( );

while (it.hasNext( )) {
    Object[] result = (Object[])it.next(); // Iterating through array object 

    userRecords.add(new User(result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7]));

    }
```